# How do I stop a call to Application.Quit from causing a pop-up box?

Tags: vba, error-handling, exit

I am writing a VBA macro that takes data from an Excel workbook and creates a PowerPoint presentation based on the data. I use the variable names ppa and ppt to refer to the PowerPoint application and the presentation, respectively.

```
Dim ppa As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Presentation
Set ppa = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set ppt = ppa.Presentations.Open(oldFileName)
```

After putting all the data in the PowerPoint file, I conclude with:

```
ppt.SaveAs(newFileName)
ppt.Close
Set ppt = Nothing
ppa.Quit
Set ppa = Nothing
```

When control hits the statement:

```
ppa.Quit
```

, I get a popup box that reads:

Microsoft PowerPoint has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program.

Worse yet, sometimes the file is saved under the new file name, and sometimes it is not. How do I modify the code to stop this from occurring?

Comment: I recreated what you did above on my machine and was able to perform the action just fine.  I would suspect it is either as David is suggesting that you have something else causing issues in your code or else you just need to reboot your computer.  Seeing the code in its entirety (or at least enough to get a sense of what else is going on) would be helpful in determining which it is.

Comment: Reboot may do it, especially if you have been developing this code and debugging live code for a while, you may have created inadvertently many PPT objects and you can get memory errors etc in those cases. STart with reboot, if the problem persists, let's see the rest of the code.

Comment: Why do you use `CreateObject` to `New` up an early-bound reference?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

After Mat's Mug's comment, I ran your code and see that there is actually powerpoint application available to quit from even if you closed your last presentation.

Well what I have discovered is, it looks like application really quits and then pops up. There might be a logical explanation of this behaviour.

So what you need to do is either wait for 1 secs to quit from application:

```
ppt.Close
Set ppt = Nothing
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
ppa.Quit
Set ppa = Nothing
```

or recreate ppa object after closing presentation.

```
ppt.Close
Set ppt = Nothing
Set ppa = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
ppa.Quit
Set ppa = Nothing
```

These 2 options are the workarounds for your crash problem.

**Edit2:**

The above-mentioned solutions work fine by me, but if you still have problem you can directly quit powerpoint like this:

```
ppt.SaveAs(newFileName)
ppa.Quit
Set ppa = Nothing
```

Comment: *If there is no powerpoint presentation, there is no powerpoint application to quit.* - that's rather unintuitive and outright confusing behavior. You can very well have an `Excel.Application` instance without an open `Workbook` object. I'm not very familiar with the ppt API /object model, but I'm looking at a PowerPoint instance right now that has no presentation loaded, so I'm not sure about that statement at all.

Comment: @Mat's Mug It seems you are right, I changed my answer due to your comment.

Comment: Can you try increasing the wait time? to be sure of it like 5 secs --> "00:00:05"

Comment: Please try my Edit2

Comment: When I put breakpoints on each statement at the bottom, it works fine.

Comment: And if you don't, does it crash?

Comment: Yes, even with your Edit2, it crashes, or at least gives the error.

Comment: Putting a breakpoint on `Set ppa = Nothing` stops the error message.

Comment: If I put a breakpoint in the few statements to follow, no error is given but the PowerPoint is in a state where it asks me if I want to save before closing.

Comment: Your original code works just fine for me. Even with a large size of presentation without adjusting anything. Remove all breakpoints and run it with F8, step by step, and see where the problem is.

Comment: Running with F8, it crashed with the same pop-up error somewhere in the middle.